# R/ggplot2 aggregation function using multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to ggplot(R) a bar graph of aggregated values based on the computation of multiple numeric columns of a table vs. some categorical column (this is also the "group by") of said table.

Table:

`V1  V2  categorical
  3   4    c1
  5   6    c2
  7   3    c2
  3   8    c3`

I would like to do something like this:

`ggplot(Table, aes(categorical)) +
  stat_summary_bin(aes="V1 * V2"), fun.y = function(r) r$V1 * r$V2)`

where the function stuffed into `fun.y` accepts a row and then accesses its corresponding V1 and V2 values to return what would be mapped to the y-axis.
The desired result would be a plot of 3 bars where c1: 12, c2: 51, and c3: 24.

Comment: A follow-up question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42036505/2019874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you just want to add the results from each row, `geom_bar` with `position = "stack"` will do just fine. `aes()` is very liberal about what you can pass to it in terms of functions of columns.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = categorical, y = V1 * V2)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to work with `stat_summary_bin`, you can specify the `fun.y` parameter as `sum`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = categorical)) +
    stat_summary_bin(aes(y = V1 * V2), fun.y = "sum", geom = "bar")
```

[image]